# How to set/allow cookie within iframe of a localhost window

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a iframe from localhost

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/abc" />
```

this page `https://www.example.com/abc` has cookie for login. but since this within the iframe the cookie was not getting set.

Also it should work on http GET requests. How does google/fb login works when there is no cookie.

How can i allow cookie, or have a fallback to something else(like cookie) which is sent on all request even if the cookie is not available(within iframe)/ not accepted(by user)/disabled.

Comment: if the iframe is for `example.com`, the network request for the iframe URL will use the cookie for `example.com` just fine (if one exists). Even though Iframes are "on your page", they are _not considered part of your website_ for very obvious security reasons.

Comment: the cookie was not getting set on example.com

Comment: Then why would it get sent? Cookies get communicated for the site they were set for (which is things like `<iframe>` or `<img>`, as well as `fetch` calls, which is what google/facebook rely on when you include their JS libraries on your site)

Comment: NO, it doesn't work.